# Can I send resources with HTTP/2 Server Push?

Tags: http2, google-app-engine-go

My webapp, written in Go, deployed on Google App Engine Standard, has handlers to generate HTML for each page (server-side rendering). It would be nice for performance if I could in certain cases (cautiously) pre-emptively send CSS and JS resources along with the HTML response, with [HTTP/2 Server Push](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2_Server_Push).

Is it possible with the Go runtime of App Engine?

(Another way of putting this: does the ResponseWriter in App Engine implement the [http.Pusher](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/?#Pusher) interface?)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be possible out-of-the-box right now:

```
if _, ok := w.(http.Pusher); ok {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "This ResponseWriter is a Pusher :)")
} else {
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "This ResponseWriter is NOT a Pusher :(")
}
```

produces

```
This ResponseWriter is NOT a Pusher :(
```

(in production, and in the local dev server as well)